# Use Victoria metrics gauge for monitor processing request

Tags: go, gauge, victoriametrics

In old version when i use prometheus client for golang. I increase and use defer decrease gauge metrics for count processing request like this

```
func (m *Middleware) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    m.gauge.Inc()
    defer m.gauge.Dec()
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

And i use query for grafana dashboard
`sum(service_name_processing[$__interval])`

Can i do it when i use victoria metrics:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics

Tks so much <3

Comment: i think you can use next approach


```golang

var num float64
func (m *Middleware) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
    num++
    defer num--
    metrics.GetOrCreateGauge(service_name_processing, func() float64 {
       return num
  })
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Comment: The Gauge metric type in metrics package accepts a callback function, which is called when /metrics page is requested. The idea is that this function will be called only when needed to collect the Gauge state and report it to the caller.

In VictoriaMetrics, Gauges are usually used like this https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/blob/e373bb84d5fce8ef82acd445d1eb73efe7777306/app/vmselect/main.go#L78-L88
To measure number of in-flight requests we use a channel to limit max-number of the in-flight requests. And channel length is used to collect the state when it is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Counter](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics#Counter) instead of Gauge. The Counter has [Inc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics#Counter.Inc) and [Dec](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics#Counter.Dec) methods.